# Xpages - Passing <ahref> in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, xpages, href, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to add a href to `Arraylist` and this adds nicely to the `Arraylist`, but the link is broken. Everything after the question mark (?) in the URL is not included in the link.

Is there anything that I'm missing, code below:

```
private String processUpdate(Database dbCurrent) throws NotesException {

int intCountSuccessful = 0;
View vwLookup = dbCurrent.getView("DocsDistribution");
ArrayList<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = vwLookup.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null) {
    String paperDistro = doc.getItemValueString("DistroRecords");
    if (paperDistro.equals("")) {
        String ref = doc.getItemValueString("ref");
        String unid = doc.getUniversalID();
        // the link generated when adding to Arraylist is broken
        listArray.add("<a href=\"gandhi.w3schools.com/testbox.nsf/distro.xsp?documentId=\"+ unid + \"&action=openDocument\">" + ref + "</a>");
    }
    Document tmppmDoc = vwLookup.getNextDocument(doc);
    doc.recycle();
    doc = tmppmDoc;
}

Collections.sort(listArray);

String listString = "";
for (String s : listArray) {
    listString += s + ", \t";
}

return listString;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with `"` escaping around `unid` value due to which you URL becomes `gandhi.w3schools.com/testbox.nsf/distro.xsp?documentId="+ unid + "&action=openDocument`.

It would be easier to read if you use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and single quotes  to generate the `a` tag:

```
listArray.add(String.format(
    "<a href='gandhi.w3schools.com/testbox.nsf/distro.xsp?documentId=%s&action=openDocument'>%s</a>", 
    unid, ref));
```

Comment: The url is still broken, everything after the question mark (?) is not included in the link.

Comment: @SamuelOmopariola the code that you posted was fixed, the `ArrayList` should have the right `a` tag values. Perhaps it's what are you doing later with the `ArrayList` that breaks the links.

Comment: The list was to be sent in an email and to do so, I used the StringBuilder. StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder("<!DOCTYPE html>") and then called the append() method.